# Как получить Responce-Headers в python urllib3

Tags: python

Мне нужно получить из Responce-Headers Location как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('http://google.ru/') as rs:
    headers = dict(rs.getheaders())
    print(headers)
    print(headers['Content-Type'])
```

Comment: можно `rs.headers` (уже как dict) напрямую использовать вместо `getheaders()` (cписок пар). Хотя `Location` http заголовок вероятно не получите, т.к. `urllib.request.urlopen()` следует по 30x перенаправлениям автоматически. Ещё заголовок вопроса содержит `urllib3`, а не  `urllib`—хотя это может быть простой опечаткой.

Comment: хм, вроде бы, когда писал ответ там был просто urllib...

Comment: [у вопроса нет правок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/523704/timeline)  и ваш ответ опубликован после окончания пятиминутного grace периода (когда правку без следа можно сделать). Но это не важно, так как вы возможно угадали, что автор вероятно хотел `urllib`, а не `urllib3`.

Answer (score 2):

Response-Headers доступны как `response.headers` в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(url) as response:
    print(response.headers['Content-Length'])
    print(response.get_content_charset('not found')) # character encoding
```

[`urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) автоматически следует по `30x` перенаправлениям, поэтому `response.headers['Location']` вы вероятно не увидите. Можно [выключить перенаправление](https://stackoverflow.com/q/554446/4279) или использовать [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) напрямую (`urlopen()` использует `http.client` внутри), чтобы получить Location http-заголовок из ответа сервера на HEAD http-запрос:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('httpbin.org')
conn.request('HEAD', '/redirect/2')
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.status)              # -> 302
print(response.headers['Location']) # -> /relative-redirect/1
```

---

Если вы хотите получить заголовки именно в [`urllib3`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/) (не из стандартной библиотеки), то немного другой пример использования, но всё равно можно `headers` атрибут использовать, чтобы получить http-заголовки из ответа:

```
import urllib3  # $ pip install urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/2', redirect=False)
print(r.status)              # -> 302
print(r.headers['Location']) # -> /relative-redirect/1
```

Вероятно, вместо `urllib3`, вы хотите [`requests` библиотеку](http://docs.python-requests.org/) использовать, которая предоставляет интерфейс более высокого уровня (`requests` использует `urllib3` внутри) и является рекомендованным http-клиентом для Питона:

```
>>> import requests  # $ pip install requests
>>> r = requests.head('http://httpbin.org/redirect/2')
>>> r.status_code
302
>>> r.headers['Location']
'/relative-redirect/1'
>>> r.history
[]
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/2')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['Location']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../requests/structures.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'location'
>>> r.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
```

Чтобы попробовать библиотеку без её установки, можно использовать версию, поставляемую с `pip`: `from pip._vendor import requests`.